# why '2'<'1'== False output False in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

```
'2'<'1'== False #False
('2'<'1')== False #True
'2'<('1'== False) #error
```

code in python3
we know operator precedence in python3
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: Isn't `'2'<'1'== False` equivalent to `('2'<'1') and ('1'== False)` which is obviously false?

Comment: It's weird behavior, but maybe https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/ helps

Comment: You are trying to compare a string to a boolean, how it is possible?

Comment: @Everyone python doesn't have concept of characters, it is a string of size 1

Comment: @Arsenic my bad, I keep thinking statically all the time.

Comment: You should consider adding C tag as well to the question.

Comment: I know nobody cares about this, so I'll add it as a comment. `'2'<'1'` isn't actually comparing string sizes. It takes each character, then compares its value to a character from the second string. If all characters are smaller than those in the second string, it will be true. When lengths do not match, it's padded (idk with what) and the pad is compared, for number character, pad is always smaller. To prove what I'm saying: `'0999' < '09999'` is `True` while `'1999' < '09999'` is `False`

Comment: @Everyone  When lengths do not match, it's padded (idk with what) ---> it is not right.

Comment: @snr what's right and how are they compared when lengths mismatch?

Answer (score 15):

### In case 1 :-

```py
'2'<'1'== False
```

it is evaluated as `'2'<'1' and '1' == False` according to the [operator chaining](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/) {thanks @ymonad to provide this link}

which will evaluated to be `False`

### in case 2 :-

```py
('2'<'1')== False
```

as `()` have higher precedence so will be evaluated first. so the expression will be reduced to `False == False` which will evaluate to be `True`

### in case 3 :-

```py
'2'<('1'== False)
```

first `('1' == False)` is evaluated which is `False` but now the operation is `'2'<False` which is an illegal operation in python

---

EDIT:

To answer a question raised by @snr in the comment section

> The vital question is why '1'== False is valid while '2'< bool is not

It is because the default behaviour for equality comparison (== and !=) is based on the identity of the objects, and as object `False` and object `'1'` does not share the same identity thus the result will be `False`

whereas a default behaviour of other comparison (<, >, <=, and >=) is not provided thus an attempt to do so raises TypeError

---

you can find this in [documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) provided by OP (under the heading value-comparisions)

Comment: Good answer, but who on earth thought it was a good idea for `a<b==c` to be changed into `a<b && b==c`... This is so counterintuitive.

Comment: @Everyone that's true, this doesn't happen in other languages like C/C++ where we have different precedence for comparison operators.

Comment: I am not aware of any other language, or any other logic operations procedure, that would make such interpretation. A program should only do what you tell it to do. We usually say this statement to people who think their programs should behave like they wish, not what they told the programs to do. Yet here, it seems the program is doing what it wishes of its own, not what you told it to do. I am once again reminded why I keep getting away from this language every time I come back.

Comment: Just for (maybe?) completeness, `'2'<'1'` is `False`, `'2'<'11'` is `False` as well. String comparison isn't actually doing length comparison as many sources claim.

Comment: @Everyone, it all starts with a good intent, `3 < blah < 4` is equivalent to `3 < blah and blah < 4` with `blah` evaluated only once. You may be used to the C like syntax but I find this more intuitive for beginners. This syntax may be misleading though: `==` is also a comparison operator and can therefore be chained with other comparison operators like in the OP's example, producing counter intuitive expressions.

Comment: The vital question is why **'1'== False** is valid while **'2'< bool** is not. That's why I didn't answer the question simply.

Comment: @snr that's a nice question. I have answered it in the edited part of the post

Comment: @Arsenic False and object '1' does not share the same identity ?? If IT DOESN'T share what about '2'< bool value ? Did you miswrite? Even if so, could you explain both cases ?

Comment: @snr it's only equality/inequality operator whose default behaviour is to check for object identity if value comparison fails. there is not such rule for other comparison operators thus it don't know what to do if objects of different types are received. look at the documentation link provided at the end of answer to get a better picture of it.

Comment: (: It means I don’t know what s going on under the Iceberg. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When python tries to do `string < string` then it turns into ascii and it orders it by alphabet order.
https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-compare-strings/

By the way, [1 ascii is 49 and 2 ascii is 50](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/number-sign-ascii-code-35.html)

#### First case

```
'2'<'1'== False #False
```

it is evaluated as `'2'<'1' and '1' == False`  which is False
because
`50 < 49 and 1 == False` -> `False and False` -> `False`

#### second case

```
('2'<'1')== False # True
```

it makes python do () first.
`(50 < 49) == False`->
`False == False` -> `True`

### third case

```
'2'<('1'== False) #error
```

first `('1' == False)` is evaluated which is False and you try to do `'2'<False`.
And it get's an error.

Python Operator Precedence: [https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html](https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Evalerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html)

Comment: Even your edited answer was a bit sloppy, @ppwater. Be a bit more careful the next time around.

Comment: @DavidHammen sorry, I will be more careful about writing answers. but thanks for editing my answer!

Comment: @ppwater No worries, your answer looks good now so I've removed my comment.

Answer (score -2):

I really tried to dig into but I can't get an answer which satisfies me. However, a person who has some time can walk through the following.

[`PyObject *tp_richcompare(PyObject *self, PyObject *other, int op);`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare) methods runs under the hood. Its implementation is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/98c4433a81a4cd88c7438adbee1f2aa486188ca3/Objects/object.c#L710).

As far as I understand, it firstly checks whether both `PyObject`s are comperable by inspecting the object types
by e.g.

```
(!Py_IS_TYPE(v, Py_TYPE(w)) &&
 PyType_IsSubtype(Py_TYPE(w), Py_TYPE(v)) &&
 (f = Py_TYPE(w)->tp_richcompare) != NULL)
```

As we can see also in your code, while `<class 'str'> __eq__ <class 'int'>` is meant to 'Yes, they are compatible with each other w.r.t. the comparison.', `<class 'str'> __lt__  <class 'bool'>` is the opposite. We are pretty sure that one of the last stations is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/boolobject.c).

```
print(type(1))
print(type('1'))
print(type(False))
print(type('1' == 1))
print('1' == 1) #False <class 'str'> __eq__ <class 'int'>
print(('2' < '1')== False) #True
#print('2'<('1'== False))  <class 'str'> __lt__ (<class 'str'> __eq__ <class 'bool'>)
# (<class 'str'> __eq__ <class 'bool'>) returns <class 'bool'>, then as a result
# <class 'str'> __lt__  <class 'bool'> comparison is not implemented.
```

*As a side note, its satisfactory answer, at least for me, must include detailed C explanations, not Pythonic*